# Is it possible to store data in molecules?

Tags: data-storage

Is it possible to store data in charged molecules? If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: How long are you hoping to store it for?

Comment: I took out your unrelated questions, but they are easy to answer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_memory

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I think he is talking about using it for long term storage; storing data literally in the cloud(s).

Comment: Hoping to store data for long term and storing the data in air around us (specifically not in clouds, everywhere around us).

Answer (score 3):

Store data as light.  Light travels at approximately 1 foot per nanosecond.  On the moon is a retro-reflector, basically a fancy mirror that reflects light back in almost exactly the same direction that it came from.  Round trip to the moon and back is 2,522,784,000 feet.  If you could send data at 1 Gbps then you could store 2,522,784,000 bits worth of information in the "air".  That's about 300 megabytes.

Of course the other question is:  is it at all practical?  No.  Not at all.  Making the machine to do this is very difficult, and expensive, and it would "replace" a $5 Thumb Drive.

There have been similar machines, however, that used coils of fiber optics instead of sending a laser to the moon.  While they were easier to make, they were much less useful.

Comment: Then the same would work for radio waves for certain frequency bands.

Comment: @jippie  Yes, it would.  Or sound waves, even.  You could go super crazy and make a juggling machine and encode data based on the color of the balls that are in the air.  :)

Comment: Thanks @David Kessner. BUt its not about sending information. Its about storing information at one place in an atmosphere(stable) like a hub. The information is made available in the air not in a hardware.

Comment: @SamGladio  Then the answer is no.  You can't do that.

Comment: @DavidKessner Why? What are the odds in implementing it?

Comment: @SamGladio  According to all of the laws of physics that I know of, your odds of succeeding given infinite funding is almost zero.  I say "almost" only because there might be something in Physic that I don't know-- but I know a lot of physics.  If you could possibly stop all wind and air currents then you might have a chance.  But you can't stop the air.

Comment: @DavidKessner Yeah you are right but how come data are transferred through air. They overcome the odds like wind and air currents to reach the user.Don't they?. The same can be implemented over here.

Comment: @SamGladio You might want to go back and re-read your high school physics textbooks... Transmission of data is not the same as static storage of data, so the wind / air currents are only marginally relevant for transmission.